# Is it possible to create a table on react-table using two or more datasets/constants?

Tags: reactjs, react-table

Good day everyone, this is my first time posting here but I'd like some help with a recent issue.

So, I'm working on a small React app just for fun and to keep practising, in it I made a few constants for different datasets (each with varying data fields), that is, I have various kinds of records categorized in said constants, since some records use 2+ rows and some need only one row.
Initially I was going to share the app's code, but the datasets are a tad... large, so reading the tips I thought I'd instead create an online sandbox to illustrate with a much simpler and smaller scenario of what I managed to do: [[link to the sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/example-of-table-in-react-from-two-datasets-jkxyub?file=/src/App.jsx)].

However, looking around and trying different stuff I found out about [react-table](https://react-table.tanstack.com/), which is what I needed due to its useful features and how lightweight it is. I mainly need it for filtering records but I want to try some other features as well.

All this brings me to my problem: I want to populate a table in react-table with the multiple datasets together and their own ways their data is placed on the JSX code, however, I can't figure out what to do and my app's code is getting messy in the process, so I thought I'd ask here to see what I can do, using the code in the sandbox as base, then I can edit my app accordingly if there's a solution for this, otherwise I guess I can maybe make one table for each dataset or just use good ol' HTML+JS+CSS? But neither are the results I'm aiming for.

I'm in no rush for answers since this is just a project for fun and to practise, however, any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it something like this you are looking for? https://codesandbox.io/s/example-of-table-in-react-from-two-datasets-forked-yd0jcm?file=/src/App.jsx

Comment: Short answer is Yes, it is possible, and it seems you are already doing that on the code shown in your link. It's not really clear what else are you trying to do.

Comment: @CharlieAraya : thanks, this is not what I want to achieve, basically what I'm looking to do is to transform a table like the one shown in my sandbox into a react-table one so that I can use its features, all while keeping the layout of the original table (with the `rowSpan` properties). However when I try to do that transformation in my project I have trouble figuring out how can I arrange the code so that react-table will recognize the datasets and use different row layouts for each of them.

Comment: @André : yes, each dataset has its own "row layout" which is basically how their records/entries show up in the table depending of the dataset, however my issue is adapting this into react-table, even for a code as small as this, I'm completely stuck on how can I make a table that uses react-table with the data I already have and what I would have to move around in the code.